# Install windows in emulator from Windows USB backup

Tags: 14.04, windows, emulation

Right now I have a dual boot system - Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04. As I only rarely use Windows I pondered on reinstalling Ubuntu so it can take over the whole disk space and install Windows in emulator. My question is whether I can fully install windows using the USB backup/recovery drive.

Comment: Yeah you can install Windows completely within the emulator using a live media.

Comment: If you're asking *how to install Windows* inside a virtual machine (hosted on a Ubuntu system), I'm afraid that's [off topic](/help/on-topic) here. I'd vote to close this question, if that was possible despite the open bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Windows on an emulator is not possible with a **"Recovery Disk"** made either using the recovery partition or the USB/DVD that came with your device **(unless it's Windows 7 or earlier)**.

The installation will halt midway or if it will even finish then you won't be able to activate it.

The newer OEM installation media only works for the devices of that OEM and that too is not cross-model compatible.
You cannot use an HP OEM disc to install on a Lenovo workstation, neither can you use a Dell Precision OEM disc on an Dell Inspirion.

The exact reasons are beyond my knowledge but it's that way right now.

Answer (score 1):

You could could use [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)  to run a virtual version of windows 10 within Ubuntu you could store the virtual image in any location you wish including a USB although it should be noted this would not be "emulating" Windows 10, it would simple be running within a virtual machine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Mmm, I thought "emulating" Windows actually means running it in a virtual machine..

Comment: @Ohm: No it doesn't: "Emulating" would be running an interpreter of one processor's instructions (like an ARM) on another processor (like an Intel Core I7 Processor).  **;-)**

Comment: @Wallermadev : Did you have experience with installing Windows on Virtualbox from Windows 10 USB recovery drive?

Comment: Could you not use a windows ISO and then restore the recovery within a clean install of windows 10.